# Multiple insertion in mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, commit, rollback

i am facing a problem in inserting into mysql tables. I have 3 related tables to insert on save, but I want to make sure that either all of the queries are run, or none of them. I have done this in C#, but I want to know how i can do it in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

In order to have a all or nothing behavior, you'll want to use a transaction :

- start the transaction
- do your queries
- if all queries have been executed successfully, commit
- else, rollback.

In PHP, if working with [**PDO**][1], you'll want to use the [**`PDO::beginTransaction()`**][2], [**`PDO::commit()`**][3] and [**`PDO::rollback()`**][4] methods.

If working with [**MySQLi**](https://www.php.net/mysqli), you'll want to use [**`mysqli::commit()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php) and [**`mysqli::rollback()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php) -- after having disabled autocommit with [**`mysqli::autocommit()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php).

To detect if a query has failed, you'll want to :

- With PDO, use [**`PDO::setAttribute()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) so exceptions are thrown when an error occurs.
- With MySQLi, [**`mysqli::query()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns `false` if a query fails.

Comment: thankz for the reply. i am using core php. but i am still confused on how to handle errors. i.e. how i can identify that an error occoured during query execyution.

Comment: It's also important to note that: 1) Transaction commands are ignored by the server unless tables use the InnoDB engine 2) No matter the API, you can also run the appropriate SQL commands manually.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide some additional informations about that. "core php" doesn't mean much : you have to use an extension *(PDO, mysql, or mysqli)* to connect to a MySQL database -- and mysql should not be used anymore *(doesn't support features introduced by recent versions of MySQL)*

Comment: @Abhilash: I don't want to sound rude but the return values and exceptions of all DB functions are perfectly explained in the PHP manual.

Comment: i am having some trouble in finding the right combination of error handling and return values. if we go by taking return value >0 as success, there will be cases when some number of rows affected will be zero. if we go by error handling methods which all methods i have to include in my error handling method... i am totally confused... please guide me..

Comment: Use PDO and exceptions -- that's the best solution :-) *(if using mysqli, don't test the number of affected rows, but test if mysqli::query returned false or not)*